# Fourier Transform of an $L^2$ Function

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+|x|}$. I just showed that $f \in L^2(\Bbb{R})$, and I'm being asked to find the $L^2$-norm of the Fourier transform. However, the formula I'm given for the Fourier transform only works for $L^1$ functions. More precisely, the lecture notes I am using defines

$$g(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-i\lambda t} dt$$

to be the Fourier transform of some function $f$, and it is remarked that this integral converges for $f \in L^1(\Bbb{R})$, but $f$ as defined above is not an $L^1(\Bbb{R})$-function.

Ignoring this for a moment, I tried to blindly apply the formula and I got the following:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-i\lambda t} dt = \int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{1-t} e^{-i \lambda t} dt + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+t} e^{- i \lambda t} dt$$

$$= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+t} e^{i \lambda t} dt + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+t} e^{- i \lambda t} dt$$

$$2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+t} Re(e^{i \lambda t})$$

$$=2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (\lambda t)}{1+t} dt$$
But I am not really sure what to do with this integral. In fact, doesn't this diverge for $\lambda = 0$, for example? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem

Comment: Different sources approach the definition of the Fourier transform on $L^2$ differently, but however defined, is usually an isometry or a fixed multiple of one (some factor involving $\pi$ might be involved). Can you compute the $L^2$ norm of $f$?

Comment: @md2perpe Unfortunately, we haven't learned that theorem yet.

Comment: @leslietownes Yes, in showing that $f \in L^{2}(\Bbb{R})$, I proved that the $L^2$-norm of it is $1$ (if I didn't screw up the calculation).

Comment: This version of the Fourier transform is exactly an isometry due to the factor out front, so the L2 norm is the same in both spaces.

Comment: What definition do you have for the Fourier transform of an $L^2$ function?

Comment: @LouisPan I don't have any definition. The only definition I have is the one given in the body of the post.

Comment: How can you be given the exercise to do something involving the Fourier transform of a $L^2 \setminus L^1$ function when you haven't learnt how that is defined?

Comment: @md2perpe Beats me. That's what I'm asking myself. I searched all the lecture notes and found nothing about Fourier transforms of functions in $L^2$ or Plancherel's theorem.

Comment: If I were you, I would probably drop such a class... I would rather learn it on my own. What book are you reading for this course?

Comment: @LouisPan There is no book; just lecture notes which usually have a profuse amount of typos. I can't drop the course at this point, but it's okay. I'm mostly taking the course because it is fully virtual and it satisfies my credit requirements. Most of the other functional analytic topics we've covered I've already learned on my own. I really only care about the functional analysis needed for operator algebras.